# How to Dynamically return SQL Datatype from Hibernate custom user type class by using @type annotation

Tags: java, hibernate

Will it possible to return SQL data type from hibernate custom user type class based on the data source(SQL/PostgreSQL). Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own usertype that based on the database bellow will translate the field. For example `@Nationalized` annotation is equivalent to `@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.StringNVarcharType")` You can write your own version that will translate the field accoring to the underlying storage.

Example: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-custom-types

Comment: -Thank you for your reply. I am a beginner in Hibernate. Could you  provide any reference link for creating Custom Data Type /User Type in Hibernate

Comment: @user335103 added.